# You know my meaning, but what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I lead to spendings, but I have no economical meaning.
I count sun trips, but I have no astronomical meaning.
I am finite, but I have no mathematical meaning.
You may like me or not, but you certainly know my meaning!

**What am I?**

Comment: Looks like a nice puzzle, with probably a very nice answer. However, there's probably going to be a bunch of "not as good but could be argued to fit all the clues" type answers: although there are many clues, all of them are kind of indirect: *anything* can lead to spendings, have birthdays and be finite, and my liking it or not (or knowing its meaning) doesn't really narrow it down very much.

Comment: Can "taxes" fit the first line :P

Comment: @CR241 Please restrict your comments to commentary. If you have an answer, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Bass Yeah, let's see. Until now I could always find arguments why the existing answers do not 100%ly match.Anyway, of course I understand your remark, but if I had added an even more direct meaning/thing, it would have been too easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> A birthday?

I lead to spendings, but I have no economical meaning.

> On birthdays, is it customary to buy gifts.

I count sun trips, but I have no astronomical meaning.

> The number of birthdays is equal to the number of sun trips one had in their life.

I am finite, but I have no mathematical meaning.

> Because it's just one day.

You may like me or not, but you certainly know my meaning!

> Lots of people hate birthdays!

Comment: Congratulations! You got it.

I had defined "finite" with the finite number of repetitions, which cause it to end, but it's possible in this way, too. :)

Answer (score 3):

> A calendar

I lead to spendings, but I have no economical meaning.

> Monthly bills, but a calendar doesn't mean anything economic inherently

I count sun trips, but I have no astronomical meaning.

> Marks trips of the sun through the sky, but daily, weekly, and months divisions have no real meaning in astronomy, they're just concepts created by us to help us keep time

I am finite, but I have no mathematical meaning.

> Either time is finite or a calendar can only display a set amount of time per individual item

You may like me or not, but you certainly know my meaning!

> We all know what calendars are for

Comment: I would argue your solution certainly has an astronomical meaning. Of course they are just concepts, but this concept is a big thing in astronomy. (see e.g. time dilation). Also, your thing has nothing special about it that would cause it to be (sometimes/by someone) unlikable.

Comment: @rugk Some people don't like schedules and prefer to take life as it comes and not schedule anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

> Perhaps it is "Age", but I don't know how it can lead to spendings.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your thought process for each line and how age fits it? Also, make sure to hide your answer behind a spoiler tag! You can do this by inserting a `>!` at the beginning of your answer.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, but actually you are on a good track.

You are even on a better track than many others here, who have more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

A

> clock?

I lead to spendings

> racing against the clock for a sale.

I count sun trips...

> it counts time, which was originally counted through a sun dial, another type of "clock".

I am finite...

> it only goes to 12 and 59.

You may like me or not

> A lot of people hate clocks if they're racing against time for something but we know what it is

Comment: "finite" – But well… it starts again then, it is a circle. So it has many infinite aspects. 

Comment: But generally a nice idea, I e.g. really like the "You may like me or not". But it's not what I had in mind.